# Is it alright to put data members in an interface?

Tags: c++, interface, composite

Recently, I've learnt about `composite pattern`. I want to use it in my assignment which I have to implement File and Folder classes. I realize that sub-classes like `CFile` and `Cfolder` got to have the same attributes (`name` and `size`). So is it alright for me to put the attributes into the `interface`? As far as I know, it is not good practice to do so. However, I don't understand why I shouldn't. Or is there any other solutions?
[image: Class Diagram]

Comment: C++ has no distinct "interface", just abstract classes. In an interface in eg. Java, it's just not possible to have variables.

Comment: If you're storing them in the abstract base class (no interfaces in C++) as public fields, then you put an implicit burden on the implementer of the derived class to keep the fields up to date.

If you put them on the base class as virtual (pure) getters, then you force the implementer to think about them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say its not a problem. Th difference is that instead of a *pure interface class* you have an *abstract base class*. However, if you want to retain the flexibility to use the *interface* for implementations that are not tied down to those specific member variables then you can always create an *interface class* as well as an *abstract base class* for full flexibility. Though that may be getting overly complex overly soon, you can always split the *interface* from the *abstract base* later if you need to.

```
using CItemUPtr = std::unique_ptr<class CItem>;

/**
 * Interface class
 */
class CItem
{
public:
    virtual ~CItem() {}

    virtual CItemUPtr findByName(std::string const& name) = 0;
    virtual void setHidden(bool a, bool b) = 0;
};

/**
 * Abstract base class
 */
class AbstractCItem
: public CItem
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::size_t size;
};

class CFile
: public AbstractCItem
{
public:

    CItemUPtr findByName(std::string const& name) override
    {
        // stuff
        return {};
    }

    void setHidden(bool a, bool b) override {}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a question of "is it a good practice". By creating an interface, you're defining a standard. The question is, do you NEED the implementation of the interface to contain those data members? You are in the best position to understand your implementation, so you're really the only one who can answer this.

As a general rule, the class implementing the interface should be a black box, and the outside world shouldn't have access to any internals (including member data). Interfaces define common functionality that is required to be present to be able to support the interface, and I'd expect those implementation details to be buried in the underlying implementation of the class only, as a general rule. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The design principle for a class should be: 
*'It is impossible to break the class invariant from the outside'* 
If the constructor(s) set up the class invariant, and all members 
uphold the class invariant, this is achieved.

However, if the class does not have a class invariant, having 
public members achieves the same thing.

```
// in C++, this is a perfectly fine, first order class
struct Pos
{
    int x,y;
    Pos& operator+=(const Pos&);
};
```

also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant

Comment: What does this have to do with interfaces?